# is_array function executes strings as well

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a function for arrays that strips the backslashes.
My problem is that I'm using the "is_array" function to verify if the input actually is an array but it seems that it executes numbers and strings as well.

The stripping part seems to work though, so it's the is_array part I can't figure out

I'm using the "array_map" function because the input array could consists of several arrays

What am I missing?

Thanks.

```
function strip_backslashes_array( $arr )
{
    $result = is_array($arr) === true ?
        array_map('strip_backslashes_array', $arr) :
        implode( "",explode("\\",$arr ));

    return $result;
}


$number = 5;
$text = 'Hey th\\\ere!';
$array = array("\\1","2\\",3,4);

$value1 = strip_backslashes_array($number);
echo $value1; 
//returns 5. I would expect it to be Null as it is NOT an array.


$value2 = strip_backslashes_array($text);
echo $value2; 
//returns "Hey there!" so it has stripped the string but I would expect Null as it is NOT an array.

echo '</br>';

$value3 = sanitize_strip_backslashes_array($array);
print_r($value3); 
//returns "Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 )" so it has stripped slashes as expected because it is an array.
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using, I only get errors like *Uncaught TypeError: explode(): Argument #2 ($string) must be of type string, int given in*

Comment: I'm running (Runtime: PHP 7.4.4)

I'll see if I can get the same error

Comment: I had `declare(strict_types=1);` set, so removing that I get `5Hey there!</br>Array`, but that shows that it's the else part of the ternary that is returning the value.  After all it's exploding on `\\` which isn't there so it just returns 5 (in the first case)

Comment: So NULL for 5 is what you want? Or are you happy with the result and just trying to figure out how it worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will strip backslashes from array and it will return null in case of other types if you give to the parameter strict `true`.

```
<?php

        function strip_backslashes_array($arr,  $strict = false){

            $isarray = is_array($arr);
        
            if ($strict && !$isarray) {
                return null;
            }
        
            return $isarray? array_map('strip_backslashes_array', $arr) :
                implode( "", explode("\\", $arr));
        
        }
        
        
        $number = 5;
        $text = 'Hey th\\\ere!';
        $array = array("\\1","2\\",3,4);
        
        echo '</br>';
        
        $value1 = strip_backslashes_array($number, true);
        var_dump($value1);
        
        
        echo '</br>';
        
        $value2 = strip_backslashes_array($text, true);
        var_dump($value2);
        
        
        echo '</br>';
        
        $value3 = strip_backslashes_array($array, true);
        var_dump($value3);
```

Comment: Nice, I would however recommend flipping the default-value of the optional parameter so that it only needs to be overridden on the internal call, and the external signature remains the same (`$strict = true`).

Answer (score 1):

Your recursion logic will not work if you want to return `null` when `is_array($arr) == false`. You wil need to use a different function to perform the string manipulation.

```php
function strip_backslashes_array( $arr )
{
    $result = is_array($arr) ?
        array_map('strip_backslashes_str', $arr) :
        null;

    return $result;
}
function strip_backslashes_str($str){
    if (is_array($str)) 
      return strip_backslashes_array($str);
    
    return implode( "", explode("\\", $str));
}
```

Comment: So what you mean is that my original function should do some if(is_array).. if(is_string) instead?

But then I guess I need to rewrite my array_map

Comment: Yes, hamza's approach looks good https://stackoverflow.com/a/73513721/6127393 .

Comment: Very nice indeed.
@Arleigh Hix your comment made me thinking though about what my intentions were with the function and if I was approaching the code in a wrong way.

But it seem that hamza fixed it in a nice way.